# How to open twitter login page from iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am developing an twitter application in which i have to create login page in application just like Facebook login dialog come.I tried STTwitter using this we have to add the twitter username and password in settings.Is there is any way to login twitter from iOS application.

This is my code

```
    - (IBAction)loginWithiOSAction:(id)sender {

    self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount];

    _loginStatusLabel.text = @"Trying to login with iOS...";
    _loginStatusLabel.text = @"";

    [_twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

        _loginStatusLabel.text = username;

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        _loginStatusLabel.text = [error localizedDescription];
    }];

}
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375785/twitter-custom-login-for-ios-app

Comment: i tried this example but in that i have to enter user name and password in settings tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't *need* to add the Twitter credentials in iOS Settings.

[STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) comes with a project named [STTwitterDemoiOS](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/tree/master/demo_ios).

This project shows how to login through the Twitter login page.

[image]

Comment: I run that code.it is showing the error the system cannot access twitter.Then i go to settings tab and i enter my userid and password then it is working properly.i am posting the code.please check it above.I am working on ios simulator.

Comment: I entered my clientkey and secret and now i am getting error STTwitterTwitterErrorDomain Code=220 "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource

Comment: You should not use `[STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount]` which is the method made to use the crendentials from iOS Settings. Just have a look at the demo project and use STTwitter the same way.

Comment: I changed that thing now i am using twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey method where i am sending my consumer key and consumer secret but it is not opening twitter login dialog and it is returning a long string format

Comment: You don't want this method. You have to do exactly as in the demo app: see https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/demo_ios/STTwitterDemoIOS/ViewController.m#L53-L74

Comment: but the thing is it is opening the twitter login page in safari browser

Comment: i want this login page should be open in app.

Comment: Then you should open the URL in a UIWebView. Note that this is considered as a bad practice, since the user cannot be sure that the app won't steal his password. The OAuth process is, among other things, made to prevent entering the Twitter password directly into apps. The user allows Twitter to issue access tokens valid for his account and some application. Your app only knows about these access tokens.

Comment: how to post using STTweeter i did...but getting this error...STTwitterTwitterErrorDomain Code=220 "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource"

Comment: @iOS_Ramesh please post your code and the expected result

Comment: How to open twitter native app for login? instead of safari. @nst

Comment: @SourabhSharma AFAIK you can't.

Comment: Thanks @nst,,,,,,Could you explain; why we can't open native app like faceook?